# Excel - Return most occurred value based on based on multiple condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have three main column `Name`, `Size`, and `Diameter`. What I want is to filter the name and return the most occurred value in `Diameter` for a particular value in `Size`. For example I have a table like below :

```
| Name | Size     | Diameter |
------------------------------
|  A   |    30    | 2232.23  |
|  A   |    30    | 2232.23  |
|  A   |    30    | 5382.98  |
|  A   |    29    | 1123.44  |
|  A   |    29    | 9323.42  |
|  A   |    29    | 1123.44  |
|  B   |    31    | 1232.11  |
|  B   |    31    | 1232.11  |
|  B   |    10    | 1111.00  |
------------------------------
```

The value that I should be receiving from `Diameter` for `A` with the `Size` of 30 is `2232.23` while for `B` I should be receiving `Diameter` value of `1232.11`  for `Size` `31`

This is just a sample of it. The actual data is more than 9000+ row. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your data is in column A,B,and C you can put this array formula in cell D1

> =INDEX(C$1:C$10,MODE(IF(A$1:A$10=A1,MATCH(B$1:B$10,B$1:B$10,{0,0}))))

[image]

Don't forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try Paste in cell D2 and drag to the last row:

=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)

It returns the number of occurrences each row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula. Formula first creates array of values that pass 2 set conditions. then IF formula removes 0 values from an array. Lastly MODE formula evaluates remained values and return the one with most occurrences.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(MODE(IF(--($A$3:$A$11000=G2)*($B$3:$B$11000=H2)*$C$3:$C$11000<>0,--($A$3:$A$11000=G2)*($B$3:$B$11000=H2)*$C$3:$C$11000,"")),MAX(--($A$3:$A$11000=G2)*($B$3:$B$11000=H2)*$C$3:$C$11000)))
```

Enter it using CTRL+Shift+Enter, since it is an array formula.

[image]

if you want to show most occurrences in ColumnD then use this formula in cell `D3` and drag it to the bottom.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(MODE(IF(--($A$3:$A$11000=A3)*($B$3:$B$11000=B3)*$C$3:$C$11000<>0,--($A$3:$A$11000=A3)*($B$3:$B$11000=B3)*$C$3:$C$11000,"")),MAX(--($A$3:$A$11000=A3)*($B$3:$B$11000=B3)*$C$3:$C$11000)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is an array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) you can try:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$20,MATCH(MODE(IF(($A$2:$A$20=E2)*($B$2:$B$20=F2)*($C$2:$C$20),($A$2:$A$20=E2)*($B$2:$B$20=F2)*($C$2:$C$20),"")),$C$2:$C$20,0),1)
```

Basically it is using `MODE` function to find the most frequent occurance and then use `INDEX/MATCH` to return the value.